# Generic async HttpClient method sometimes doesn't work?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm creating an application with *Xamarin.Forms* which consume from **SOAP services** using **POST method**; I have a bunch of services that work correctly, indeed, one of these methods is used to send information in multiple cases and my problem is related with this.

I have the following HttpClient method, but sometimes doesn't work... unfortunately I don't have access to back-end code and they are not for the labour of help me with that.

Any idea about how to improve my method or get any approach to the real error? I'm stuck here, since I send the same fields each time.

```
public async Task<string> InvokeAsync (string uri, string xmlSOAP) {
try {
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler () { UseCookies = false })

    using (var client = new HttpClient (new NativeMessageHandler ())) {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add (new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue ("application/xml"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("Pragma", "no-cache");
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds (timeout);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl.NoCache = true;

        var req = new HttpRequestMessage (HttpMethod.Post, uri) 
        {
            Content = new StringContent (xmlSOAP, Encoding.UTF8)
        };
        req.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse ("text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        if (uri.ToLowerInvariant ().Equals (jsessionUrlCheck)) {
            if (jsession != null && jsession.Count > 0) {
                foreach (var cookie in jsession) {
                    req.Headers.Add ("JSESSIONID", cookie);
                }
            }
            jsession = null;
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync (req);
        string responseBodyAsText = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync () : string.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (responseBodyAsText))
        {
            return responseBodyAsText;
        }

        return null;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.WriteLine ("========= InvokeAsync Exception =========");
    Debug.WriteLine ("Error: " + e.Message);
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Is an error thrown, do you get back garbage data?

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea about how to [...] get any approach to the real error?

It sounds like you don't really know what exactly happens when it "doesn't work". The way you approach the real error is by finding out what exactly happens in this code when it is reported not to work.

Do you have logs? Check the logs. If the exception is there, that should point you in the right direction. Exception not there? Maybe start logging the data received too. No logs? Start logging; there's no better way to handle intermittent failures that you can't reproduce on demand.